# VBA to click on web link

Tags: vba

i want to click on link which have onclick javascript code

```
<a href="#" onclick="if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function'){jsfcljs(document.forms['SideForm'],{'SideForm:j_id40':'SideForm:j_id40'},'');}return false">
 <li>Claim Status</li></a>
```

my tried code =

```
Document.getElementById("Document.getElementById("j_id40").Click").Click
```

so please help.

Comment: please show your whole code, plus some more of the source code of website

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add more data like what you're trying to do or the site itself. Also check out if you absolutely need to use VBA, there are a lot of browser automation software out there.

Cheers,
Sujoy

Answer (score 0):

**CSS selector and .querySelector method:**

You could try the [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method of HTMLDocument to apply a [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors). For the HTML shown you can use a full

```
a[onclick*="if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function'){jsfcljs(document.forms['SideForm'],{'SideForm:j_id40':'SideForm:j_id40'},'');}return false"]
```

or shorten to:

```
a[onclick*="if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function')"]
```

Whether you can shorten depends on whether there are any other elements which match the pattern and come before the one of interest.

**Explanation:**

The CSS pattern is an `a` tag, with an `onclick` attribute containing the string either `if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function')`, for the short version, or `if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function'){jsfcljs(document.forms['SideForm'],{'SideForm:j_id40':'SideForm:j_id40'},'');}return false` =, for the longer version

---

Example CSS selection using selector:

[image: CSS selector query]

---

**VBA:**

To apply this with VBA you use:

```
IE.document.querySelector("a[onclick*='if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function')']")
```

I have replaced the inner `"` with ' to save on having to double up on `"` to escape `"` with a string.

Otherwise it would look like:

```
IE.document.querySelector("a[onclick*=""if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function')""]")
```